# Job recommendations tag names too long

Tags: bug, design, firefox, stack-overflow-jobs

With long tag names, the tag boundaries can overlap with the recommendation box border. Reproduced with `Firefox 56.0.2 64bit`, not reproducable with `Chrome 61.0.[...] 64bit` or `Edge 40.15063.674.0`.

[image]